# Can no longer boot into windows after installing fedora

Tags: fedora, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I finally decided I would dual boot my windows 11 machine with Linux. I shrunk my windows partition, installed fedora, and it is working great. The problem is that I cannot get back to windows as it is not in the Grub menu.

I can see the files are still there but I am not too sure where to go from here as to how to get it into the Grub menu so I can boot back into it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to install `os-prober` on your Fedora installation, which is a tool that enhances GRUB to explicitly look for bootable OS's on non-primary partitions.

So, install `os-prober` with RPM, and then update GRUB:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2#Updating_the_GRUB_configuration_file

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help. I tried to install os-prober but it said I already had it installed. I made sure my windows partition was mounted. I then updated grub and the output of that command was "Generating grub configuration file ...
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done"

I still do not see windows in the grub menu

Comment: It could very well be that fedora installed over the Windows EFI and it it must be rebuild somehow. Would you mind sharing your partition scheme in your original question?